# application running in Background when form is hidden

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have two forms "login form" and "dashboard form". When i successfully connected to database through login form, it hides and dashboard form appears. But the problem is, even if i close dashboard form, my application is still running in background.

What should i do to avoid my application run in background?

This is my code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.Hide();
       Form2 form = new Form2();
       form.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: so you want the dashboard form to also close the login form when the dashboard form exits?

Comment: @trashr0x yes i need to close login form too by closing dashboard form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hiding does not mean terminating the program.

What you can do is override `OnFormClosing` on `dashboardForm`

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
    if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.WindowsShutDown && !UserDidQuit)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle `Form2`'s `FormClosed` event as below:

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close the form after the dialog is closed.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Hide();
   Form2 form = new Form2();
   form.ShowDialog();
   this.Close();
}
```